# How does XMP define the face region?

Tags: tagging, xmp

I cannot get hold of the XMP standard at the moment, all linked pages seem to be down. I would like to know how it defines the region of interest, e.g. to mark a face. As far as I remember, I should specify the centre of RoI and its width and height, with relative coordinates. But which corners do (0, 0) and (1, 1) correspond to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XMP files created by Lightroom seems to follow the [MWG description](http://www.metadataworkinggroup.com/schemas/regions/) (website currently down), as it contains this link to describe its content :

> xmlns:mwg-rs="http://www.metadataworkinggroup.com/schemas/regions/"

I took a random XMP file from one of my picture containing a recognized person : the part *mwg-rs:Region* is structured as follows :

```
<mwg-rs:Regions rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <mwg-rs:AppliedToDimensions
     stDim:w="4731"
     stDim:h="3154"
     stDim:unit="pixel"/>
    <mwg-rs:RegionList>
     <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li>
       <rdf:Description
        mwg-rs:Rotation="-0.15987"
        mwg-rs:Name="The name part"
        mwg-rs:Type="Face">
       <mwg-rs:Area
        stArea:h="0.17613"
        stArea:w="0.11730"
        stArea:x="0.42527"
        stArea:y="0.35826"/>
       </rdf:Description>
      </rdf:li>
     </rdf:Bag>
    </mwg-rs:RegionList>
</mwg-rs:Regions>
```

You can see that for this image, the region is specified by an "Area" structure, containing 4 values, which appear to be percentages relative to the whole image :

- stArea:x and stArea:y are the coordinates of the center of the area, relative to the upper left corner of the image
- stArea:h and stArea:w are the height and the width

So to answer your question, **(0,0) is the upper left corner** of the pictures and **(1,1) is the lower right corner**.

As a side note, I don't know how the "Rotation" parameter of the mwg-rs Description part comes to play: at your place, I would make some tests :)

Comment: Thanks for answering about the coordinate system. However: are you sure stArea:x, y refer to the corner of the area? I would expect (and also vaguely remember) that it's the centre.

Comment: I found my own [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595560) where the exampl shows that (x, y) probably define the centre of the region (x+w and y+h are both >1).

Comment: You are right regarding the area:x and area:y parameters, I edited my answer.